# Not getting the correct output on a function that returns the number of digits divisible by another

Tags: python

I'm currently writing a function that is supposed to take two integers (n and m) as arguments and then return the number of digits in `n` that are divisible by `m`. (If a digit is 0, it is divisible by any number)

An example of this could be (650899, 3) (n, m) and the answer is 4 (because 0, 6, and 9, are all divisible by 3).

I'm getting the correct output for some values that I put through the function, but not all of them. Can anyone see my error here? I also want to be able to put negative values of `n` through the function and have it give me a result.

Here's my code so far:

```
def divisible_digits(n, m):
    count = 0
    for i in range(n, m):
        if (i % m == 0):
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: Why do you ask the same question again?  those earlier answers did not help you?

Comment: No, I'm having a different issue here

Comment: What is this line supposed to do?  `for i in range(n, m)` ? Ever working?  You could try to run through http://pythontutor.com/ to see how your code is running first.

Comment: I tried running it through pythontutor.com, but it only showed me one live step

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
def diviisble_digits(n, m):
    sn = str(n)
    return sum(1 for d in sn if int(d)%m == 0)

diviisble_digits(n, m)  # n, m = 650899, 3
4
```

Comment: I'm unable to use any form of `str` in this challenge, which was part of the issue

Comment: Well, it's not stated in your problem description. Right?  Can you specify clearly what's the constraint then?  `str` is Python basic type, wonder why cannot use it!